# How to spell an AMOUNT into WORDS with respect to the convention of BRITISH/COMMONWEALTH LANGUAGE in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I am currently using this code to convert a number/amount into words:

SELECT UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(A.Amt,'J'),'JSP')) FROM TABLE A

If I have Amt= 512

The answer is "five hundred twelve"

But this in American English.

How can I have an input as "five hundred **and** twelve"

which is British English.

EDIT:

Thank you all for your input.

Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(MAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp')AS AMERICAN_ENGLISH,
CASE
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(mAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp') like '%Hundred%' AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(mAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp') NOT LIKE '%Thousand%'
THEN REGEXP_replace(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(MAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp'),'\s',' and ',1,2)
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(mAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp') like '%Thousand%' AND
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(mAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp') NOT LIKE '%Hundred%' AND CEIL(MAX(A.Amt)) > 1000
THEN REGEXP_replace(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(mAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp') ,'\s',' and ',1,2)
WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(MAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp') like '%Hundred%' AND  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(MAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp')  LIKE '%Thousand%'
THEN REGEXP_replace(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(MAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp'),'\s',' and ',1,4)
ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(MAX(A.Amt)),'J' ),'Jsp')
END AS BRITISH_ENGLISH
FROM TABLE1  A
```

EVEN BETTER SOLUTION THAT I MANAGED TO CODE. IT CATERS FOR ALL AMOUNT.

```
SELECT 
        REGEXP_replace(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(A.Amt), 'J'), 'Jsp'),
                         ' ',
                         ' and ',(instr(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CEIL(A.Amt), 'J'), 'Jsp'),' ',-1)))
  FROM TABLE A
```

Comment: what about getting that string and replace the LAST space with ' and '? the INSTR function can also process from end (- values for index)

Comment: I'm not sure it's even American English - e.g. 501101 becomes  "FIVE HUNDRED ONE THOUSAND ONE HUNDRED ONE".  It's just not putting ANDs in because it's hard to work out when they are needed I imagine.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Thank you for your input. Indeed I just had to find a way to replace the last space. I tried INSTR though but it gave the -1 is out of range. So I hardcoded to include replacement for last space in every possible scenario in my case. It's definitely not foolproof but it will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function will do it for you:

```
create or replace function nummber_to_english
   ( p_number integer
   ) return   varchar2
is
   result long;
   millions integer;
   hundred_thousands integer;
   thousands integer;
   hundreds integer;
   units integer;
begin
   millions := floor(p_number/1000000);
   hundred_thousands := floor(mod(p_number,1000000)/100000);
   thousands := floor(mod(p_number,100000)/1000);
   hundreds := floor(mod(p_number,1000)/100);
   units := mod(p_number,100);

   result := trim(regexp_replace (case when millions > 0 then to_char(to_date(millions*1000000,'J'),'JSP') end
          || ' ' || case when hundred_thousands > 0 then to_char(to_date(hundred_thousands*100,'J'),'JSP') end
          || ' ' || case when (millions > 0 or hundred_thousands > 0) and thousands > 0 then ' AND' end 
          || ' ' || case when thousands > 0 then to_char(to_date(thousands,'J'),'JSP') end
          || ' ' || case when hundred_thousands > 0 or thousands > 0 then ' THOUSAND' end
          || ' ' || case when hundreds > 0 then to_char(to_date(hundreds*100,'J'),'JSP') end
          || ' ' || case when (millions > 0 or hundred_thousands > 0 or thousands > 0 or hundreds > 0) and units > 0 then ' AND' end 
          || ' ' || case when units > 0 then to_char(to_date(units,'J'),'JSP') end, '( ){2,}',' '));
   return result;
end;
```

For example:

```
     33 THIRTY-THREE
    512 FIVE HUNDRED AND TWELVE
   1000 ONE THOUSAND
   1022 ONE THOUSAND AND TWENTY-TWO
 100000 ONE HUNDRED THOUSAND
 100001 ONE HUNDRED THOUSAND AND ONE
 500101 FIVE HUNDRED THOUSAND ONE HUNDRED AND ONE
 501101 FIVE HUNDRED AND ONE THOUSAND ONE HUNDRED AND ONE
1000000 ONE MILLION
1000001 ONE MILLION AND ONE
1000081 ONE MILLION AND EIGHTY-ONE
1000101 ONE MILLION ONE HUNDRED AND ONE
1200081 ONE MILLION TWO HUNDRED THOUSAND AND EIGHTY-ONE
1234567 ONE MILLION TWO HUNDRED AND THIRTY-FOUR THOUSAND FIVE HUNDRED AND SIXTY-SEVEN
1500101 ONE MILLION FIVE HUNDRED THOUSAND ONE HUNDRED AND ONE
1523101 ONE MILLION FIVE HUNDRED AND TWENTY-THREE THOUSAND ONE HUNDRED AND ONE
```

**Note**: as with the standard Oracle method, this only works for integers between 1 and 5373484.

Comment: Thanks... Hard-coding suits my need as for my purpose I do not go beyond the thousands.